# Apex scheduler - execution may be delayed based on service availability

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

According to Salesforce's documentation:

"*Salesforce schedules the class for execution at the specified time. Actual execution may be delayed based on service availability.*"

When is the service not available?

Source: [apex scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multi-tenant system. Your server may be loaded up with requests at the time the job is scheduled to execute. You should read through these documents:

- [The Force.com Multitenant Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture)
- [Asynchronous Processing in Force com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com)

  - Specifically, read up on Resource Conservation:

    > Asynchronous processing in Force.com is very important but has lower priority over real-time interaction via the browser and API. Message handlers run on the same application servers that process interactive requests, and it's possible that asynchronous processing or increased interactive usage can cause a sudden increase in usage of computing resources.
    >
    > To ensure there are sufficient resources to handle a sudden increase, the queuing framework will monitor system resources such as server memory and CPU usage and reduce asynchronous processing when thresholds are exceeded. If necessary, under heavy load, Salesforce will delay long running jobs in the queue to give resource priority to synchronous requests. Once the resources fall below thresholds, normal asynchronous processing will continue.
  - Also read up on **Fair Request Handling**.

    > An organization can have many requests outstanding. For example, a single organization could queue 250,000 @future Apex requests in a 24-hour period, depending on Salesforce license type. If one organization adds a large number of requests to the queue, it could prevent other customers from getting access to the worker threads. To avoid this, the queuing framework implements flow control which prevents a single customer from using all of the available threads.
    >
    > When a worker thread is available to process a request, the queuing framework will determine if the maximum number of worker threads (as determined by the handler) is being used by a single organization. If so, the framework will "peek" into the queue to see if other organizations have requests waiting. The set of requests is called the peek set and is limited to a fixed number of requests at the front of the queue (currently set at 2,000 requests). The framework will look for the requests for a different organization and process those (as long as that organization isn’t currently consuming all of its allocated threads for a given handler).